# Unsure of which multidimensional nearest neighbour algorithm to use

Tags: c++, data-mining, kdtree, r-tree

I'm currently working on a project that requires a thread to construct a queue of 30(ish) nearest processes closest to the player within a 3D environment.

All of these processes can move about the environment, as well as leave their starting nodes that they were placed in. I have considered using R trees, but due to its ludicrously high insert times, it does not seem very viable.

KD- Trees would not work, since they tend to only work for static environments.

Note also that this will be running async to the main update thread, so an atomic approach would work best.

Can someone suggest an approach?

Comment: R-trees can work well. Insert times depend a lot on the quality of your implementation... Same for kd-trees. They are well worth a try. But for games (in 2d or 3d), don't overlook the most boring approaches ever: grids, quadtrees, etc. To avoid locking, consider a log-structured approach, for example.

Comment: Hmm, most of the R-Tree implementations I saw had similar insert times to std::map. It was a bit too slow for my taste. Can you provide sources to a faster one?

I did tree quad and octree as well. Neither one seemed to meet my requirements perfectly, and created a substantially large memory footprint.

Comment: Don't use a library. Write it yourself, to save all that overhead that you found unacceptable.

Comment: Oh, sorry. By sources I meant source to a paper. Not actual source code haha.

Comment: Scientific papers can be even more misleading when it comes to real-world performance, unfortunately. And I don't know if there is one explaining quadtrees, actually. You may also want to look at BSP trees, which according to Wikipedia are often used in 3D games.

Comment: I did figure out a solution. Not all the processes are dynamic. Only about 20% of them. So what I can do is assume that the processes will move to the static ones if the player picks them up.

IE: He picks up a sandwich, and carries it to his job. Both the sandwich and job are processes. (I should have referred to them as advertisements for this explanation).

I can just use a static KD-Tree and overlay the dynamic ads.